# Discovering the form of exponentials in poset category

Tags: category-theory

I'm in Awodey, page 129. Given a Boolean algebra $P$ viewed as a poset category, we can define the exponential $c^b$ for $c, b \in P$. The definition of an exponential is: an object $c^b$ and an arrow $\epsilon: c^b \times b \to c$ such that for all $a$ and $f: a \times b \to c$, there is unique $\bar{f}: a \to c^b$ with $\epsilon \circ (\bar{f} \times 1_b) = f$.

In this poset setting (where there is at most one arrow between two objects), this means: an object $c^b$ and an arrow $\epsilon: c^b \times b \to c$ such that for all $a$ and arrows $f: a \times b \to c$, there is an arrow $\bar{f}: a \to c^b$ with $\epsilon \circ (\bar{f} \times 1_b) = f$.

Let $a \times b = \text{GLB}(a, b)$ be the greatest lower bound of $a$ and $b$. Then this means an object $c^b$ and an arrow $\epsilon$ demonstrating that $\text{GLB}(c^b, b) \leq c$, such that for all $a$ with $\text{GLB}(a, b) \leq c$, have $a \leq c^b$.

Now, Awodey says that $c^b = (\neg b \vee c)$. My question is, how would one notice this? Once it's written down, I can follow through the manipulations to show it's correct; and if we have access to the corresponding fact from the category of proofs that $A \Rightarrow B$ is $B^A$, then it is certainly suggested by the functor-like thing sending proof-terms to sets in a model. Is there a way to see that $\neg b \vee c$ is an exponential just from the poset-category facts, without having to make an inspired guess?

Comment: I don't see a good way to guess without having the logical semantics in mind.

Comment: As an aside, the premise that it is a *Boolean* algebra is crucial to the conclusion -- e.g. in Heyting algebras, you often have that $c^b $ is *not* $\neg b \vee c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential $C^B$ is the "largest" object in the poset whose meet with $B$ is less than or equal to $C$.  This can be seen from the fact that:

$A \wedge B \leq C$ iff $A \leq C^B$ together with the trivial $C^B \leq C^B$.

In a poset with a bottom, $\neg B$ is the "largest" element of the poset such that $B \wedge \neg B = \bot$.

The object $\neg B \vee C$ is the "smallest" element of the poset which is greater than both $C$ and $\neg B$.  If we were to make an object $X$ which is "bigger" than this one, we would no longer have the property that $X \wedge B \leq C$.  $\neg B \vee C$ is bigger than $C$ but only by the least upper bound in common with $\neg B$, which is the largest object whose meet with $B$ is the bottom.

The connection with logic is that $C^B$ is the "weakest" premise which, together with $B$ entails $C$.  It's obvious that the weakest premise of this kind is $B \Rightarrow C$ since it assumes noting other than the fact that $B$ follows from $C$.